# Vectors in row space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's state a $m*n$ matrix $A$ with $rank(A) < n $ and two vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$. If $x_1 \in row(A)$ and $x_2 \in row(A)$, how did we prove that $A^TAx_1 \neq A^TAx_2$ unless $x_1 = x_2 $.By intuition, we could say that's correct. How do we make the prove complete? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Take $A=0$ and $x_1\neq x_2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The row space of the zero matrix isn't too interesting.

Comment: @DietrichBurde A cannot be zero and sorry for the confusion. I've updated the problem.Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: $N(A^\top A) = N(A)$; thus, if $(A^\top A)x_1=(A^\top A)x_2$, then $x_1-x_2$ lies in both the row space of $A$ and the nullspace of $A$ (which is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace).